# Export Excel 3D chart using VBA to the image

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I know how to export a regular chart, but now I am looking is it possible (at all?) to export Excel 3D chart to JPG file? These types of charts are generated using Data Analysis Add-in.

Comment: Consider using Analysis TollPak - VBA, it has a kind of Debug Mode, maybe will help. More info [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/analysis-toolpak-vba.htm).

Comment: What kind of chart? And does it have to be a 3D chart, which are notoriously bad at showing data accurately?

Comment: Jon, it is a 3D chart that comes from Excel add-in Data Analysis.